# Why is my setter not working on an anonymous struct field?

Tags: struct, go, setter

I'm just learning Go, and here's some behaviour I can't quite get my head around:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Message interface {
    SetSender(sender string)
}

type message struct {
    sender string
}

type Join struct {
    message
    Channel string
}

func (m message) SetSender(sender string) {
    m.sender = sender
}

func main() {
    var msg Message
    msg = Join{}
    msg.SetSender("Jim")
    fmt.Printf("%s", msg)
}
```

This prints `{{} }`, so the `SetSender` call doesn't seem to take effect. I suspect that it is somehow operating on a copy of the `message`, but I can't figure out where such a copy would come from. I tried changing `SetSender` to operate on `*message` but that won't compile.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/yNdnM1bfSG

Suggestions for alternative design patterns are also welcome. I have several types of messages (only `Join` is shown here), but they all have some fields in common (only `sender` is shown here). I'd like to avoid having to write and export a separate constructor for each message type, so it would be great if I can just keep exporting the types themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use pointer to message, not a message.

```
func (m *message) SetSender(sender string) {
    m.sender = sender
}

func main() {
    var msg Message
    msg = new(Join)
    msg.SetSender("Jim")
    fmt.Printf("%s", msg)
}
```

It will change the structure. Function on `message` changes copy of the object, function on pointer to `message` changes the object.

http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/methods-on-structs.html

Comment: it's the difference between passing by value and passing by reference.  Passing a pointer is a reference to the original object, so it can be changed. Passing a value is a clone of the original object, any changes made to it will not change the original object.